# Send form to SQLdatabase ( 405 not allowed)

Tags: php, html, mysql, nginx

So i have this web page:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/inputstyle.css">
  <title>Database Input</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Database Input Page </h1>
    <p> Here you can input to the Database </p>
    <a href="View.html">View Database.</a>

    <form submit="submit.php" method="post">
        <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
        <p>Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" /></p>
        <p>Age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this php script:

```
<?php

$username="root";
$password="password";
$database="posts";
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
mysql_connect(serverip,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to connect to Database");
$query = "INSERT INTO input  
VALUES('$firstname','$surname','$age')";mysql_query($query);mysql_close();

?>
```

In my mySQL database i have the database 'posts' and the table `input`. Withing the input table I only have 3 columns which in order are `firstname`, `surname` and `age`.

I need to get this working for a school project, but when I try and submit the form i get the error `405 Not Allowed`. This is my first time using php and mySQL so im not sure if i've made any errors. Also all of my web files are located within `/usr/share/nginx/html`, although i do have a subfolder withing that for css.

Comment: what is the table structure of input ?

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty table structure is - firstname, surname, age if thats what you mean?

Comment: yes do u have some other cols like primary key and all ? please post the entire structure on question.

Comment: hmm could be some server mis configuration also

Comment: Read this article on the suject => http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html @dat_guy I also deleted my answer since you used my answer to change your variables. If you're on a hosted site, then check with your hosting provider.

Comment: Actually, I undeleted my answer. See my top edit. @dat_guy

Comment: @Fred -ii- Well I am hosting the website from my CentOS server (which i rent from a VM supplier) So do you think that its the VM supplier that may have disabled POST requests? Or that I have set up my VM incorrectly?

Comment: Reload my answer @dat_guy I made an edit 8-10 mins. ago and called you in there also.

Comment: You will need to contact them to see if that is the case then. @dat_guy It could be anything.

Comment: @Fred -ii- You asked to keep you informed, and the reason is because my VM hosting doesnt allow POST requests. I tried it on the school's VM and it worked fine

Comment: @dat_guy Thanks for that. I'm glad to know that you were able to get some answers :) Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit:

You have: (*submit*)

```
<form submit="submit.php" method="post">
      ^^^^^^
```

change it to: (*action*)

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
```

---

#### Original answer from [**OP's original question/code**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22747866/1)

POST variables are case-sensitive.

You have:

- `<input type="text" name="firstname" />`
- which is called using `$firstname=$_POST['First Name'];`

  that is wrong for two reasons.

  1. It's supposed to be `$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];`
  2. Your present variable contains as space.

You also have:

- `<input type="text" name="surname" />`
- is called using `$surname=$_POST['Surname'];`

which should be `$surname=$_POST['surname'];`

Then

- `<input type="text" name="age" />`
- which is called by `$age=$_POST['Age'];` but should be `$age=$_POST['age'];`

This line I'm unsure of `mysql_connect(serverip,$username,$password);` `serverip` is undefined.

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: Thanks, I changed removed the caps and the space from those variables; but I still get the '405 Not Allowed' error on submission of the form. (also, where it says 'serverip' I actually just have my server's ip, but I changed it to 'serverip' just to ask in the question - the same as 'password' is not my actual password)

Comment: See my **Edit** @dat_guy Reload my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing it from 'submit' to 'action' but I still have the same problem (Error 405)

Comment: Another thing which could be at play here, is that you're doing `"INSERT INTO input  
VALUES('$firstname','$surname','$age')"` try using actual columns as your INSERTs --- I.e.: `"INSERT INTO input (firstname,surname,age) 
VALUES('$firstname','$surname','$age')"` @dat_guy depending on the name of your columns. Plus, contacting your VM provider also.

Comment: I also noticed you're using `<a href="View.html">View Database.</a>` to "view database". `.html` files will not process PHP/SQL using `.html` as an extension, unless you instruct Apache to treat `.html` as PHP. @dat_guy Are all your files set as `.php` files?

Comment: I currently Have 2 html pages (input and view) and was planning on having a PHP script on the view database page to create a html table and insert the mySQL tables into it. Im not sure if thats possible, as I said in my original question im very new to both mySQL and PhP

Comment: It's entirely possible, however the 405 method error first needs to be addressed and fixed ASAP. @dat_guy Otherwise, you won't be able to continue, unfortunately.

Comment: I think for now I will have to leave it and move onto the other page (I can manually fill my SQL database with test values for now). As I said its a school project, so i think as long as the actual code is correct, it should be fine for now (I can also test it on the schools VM when im there next, but I cant access those from home which is why im currently doing it on my own personal VM)

Comment: Ok. Try and keep me posted. I will gather up a few links that you can check out to query your DB and display. @dat_guy

Comment: These ought to help out http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/03/23/mysqli-tutorial-connect-select-display-close/ and 

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm and

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Display-Data-P281.html

you can also Google "mysql display data in html table" where you find many other good tutorials. @dat_guy Cheers

Comment: In addition to one of the links I left you above http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Display-Data-P281.html there's more links below that tutorial that shows you how to do a lot of other things too, which I've used before. @dat_guy and this is a good one too using `mysqli_*` functions (with prepared statements) http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452